# JQuery Datepicker hide dates from one calendar on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have several datepickers on the same page and need one to only display the month and year, while others should show complete calendar with days. I know that to hide days from a lone datepicker I can do something like:

```
<style>
 .ui-datepicker-calendar {
   display: none;
 }
</style>
```

But that hides the dates from all calendars. How can I make sure the other datepicker keeps the calendar view?

**Edit**
I did try nesting CSS but am still missing something. For HTML part I have roughly:

`<div id="monthOnly"><input type="text" class="monthly-picker" name="mdate"></div>`

And  JS code `$('.monthly-picker').datepicker();`

Still, doing something like

```
<style>
#monthOnly .ui-datepicker-calendar {
   display: none;
 }
</style>
```

Does not produce desired results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

give the use an id on a container element.

```
<style>
 #monthOnly .ui-datepicker-calendar {
   display: none;
 }
</style>
```

EDIT:
http://jsfiddle.net/h8DWR/ is a solution to deal with the idiosyncrasies of datepicker.  The idea is use a style element to add the style when the specific datepicker is chosen and then remove it when it is closed.

Comment: @DangerMonkey lol when I saw this question I was waiting for the flood of all the same answers.

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example? Say, I have the text field coded up like so: `<div id="monthOnly"><input type="text" class="monthly-picker" name="mdate"></div>` and have JS code `$('.monthly-picker').datepicker();` - the style you provide does not work in that case.

Comment: @SaltyNuts here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h8DWR/ It isn't the cleanest solution, but it should work.  The problem is the datepicker doesn't seem to have been designed with your usage case in mind.

Answer (score 2):

I did a little different ...

**HTML**

```
<label for="startDate">Date :</label>
<input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
```

**CSS**

```
.hide-calendar .ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        yearRange: '1980:' + new Date().getFullYear(),
        beforeShow: function(el, dp) { 
            $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass('hide-calendar');
        },
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            $('#ui-datepicker-div').removeClass('hide-calendar');
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nymos/DBpJe/2436/)

Comment: To avoid the display on close, I have added a timeout `setTimeout(function() {$('#ui-datepickerdiv').removeClass('hide-calendar');}, 300);`

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different way

```js
$('.year').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: true,
  dateFormat: 'MM yy',
  beforeShow: function(input) {
    $(this).datepicker('widget').addClass('hide-calendar');
  },
  onClose: function(input, inst) {
    $(this).datepicker('widget').removeClass('hide-calendar');
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
  }
});

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: true,
  dateFormat: 'MM yy dd',
  onClose: function(input, inst) {
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay));
  }
});
```

```css
.hide-calendar .ui-datepicker-calendar{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input class="year" type="text" id="" />
<input class="datepicker" type="text" id="" />
```